# How test a function that has been called or not in jest

Tags: typescript, react-native, jestjs

This is my example code, here I need to test the ***regenerate*** function after component mounts and I need to make sure that ***qrCodeUrl*** has been changed or not for ***Qrcode*** component

```
export function Component() { 
 const [qrCode, setQrCode] = useState("initialUrl");

const regenerate = () => {
   getUrl = ApiCall;
   serQrCode(getUrl);
}

useEffect(() => {
  const regenerate = async () => {
    const qrCodeUrl = await someCall();
    setQrCode(qrCodeUrl);
  };
  regenerate(); 
}, [])

return (
   <View testID="qrCodeWrapper">
     <Qrcode url={qrCode} />
   </View>
)

}
```

and this is my test file

```
test("Has to ensure that QR code is refreshed", async () => {
    const { environment, getByTestId } = render(Component);
    await resolveMostRecentOperation<ComponentQuery>(environment);
    const qrCodeWrapper = getByTestId("qrCodeWrapper");
    expect(qrCodeWrapper.props.children).toBeDefined();
    expect(qrCodeWrapper.props.children.props.url).toBe(`${appConfig.baseUrl}snapshot/initialUrl`);
  });
```

This test is working fine but I am unable to get the updated ***url*** after component mounts, it always showing ***initialUrl***

lang: *react-native, jest, @testing-library/react-native*

Comment: By any chance, are you using enzyme as well?

Comment: No, I am not using